# How to apply a scrollbar to a frame in a canvas

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm having a really hard time trying to achieve a decdent GUI layout in tkinter. I'm aiming for the layout on the left, but didn't get any further than the layout on the right:

[image]
[image]

I feel completely lost in all that different layout managers. This is my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *

class ScrolledCanvas:
    def __init__(self, master, width=500, height=350):
        Label(master, text="top of master frame").pack(side=TOP)
        self.control=Frame(master)
        self.control.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X, padx=2)
        Label(self.control, text="bottom of master frame").pack()
        self.grid = Frame(master, bd=2, bg="red")
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, relief=SUNKEN, borderwidth=2, 
                             scrollregion=('-11c', '-11c', '50c', '20c')) 
        self.vscroll = Scrollbar(master, command=self.canvas.yview) 
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vscroll.set) 

        self.grid.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.grid.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=0)
        self.grid.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=0)

        self.canvas.grid(padx=1, in_=self.grid, pady=1, row=0,
                         column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky='news')
        self.vscroll.grid(padx=1, in_=self.grid, pady=1, row=0,
                          column=1, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky='news')
        self.oldFill = None
        self.canvas = self.fillCanvas(self.canvas)

    def fillCanvas(self, theCanvas):
        for i in range(10):
            frame = Frame(theCanvas)
            Label(frame, text="text for inner frame (%s)" % i).pack(side=TOP)
            Button(frame, text="button %s.1" % i).pack(side=LEFT)
            Button(frame, text="button %s.2" % i).pack(side=LEFT)
            frame.pack()
        return theCanvas

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    scroll = ScrolledCanvas(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

For some reason the scrollregion expands to full size, making all scrollbar actions obsolete (This code bases on a scrollbar example where the canvas is filled with some rectangles, and everything scrolls really nice). I probably missed something fundamental about resizing, because most components seem to completely ignore their fixed width and height.

I'm looking for help on how to get *this example* to work with tkinter. I know that there are other layout technologies, and I know that other modules offer scrollable widgets out of the box. But unless completely unavoidable I really like to stick to this example, which cost me at least 3 nights so far...

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but you may want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-grid-of-widgets-in-tkinter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pack (or grid, or place) widgets into the canvas and expect them to scroll. Instead, you must use the [create_window](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method) method.

Comment: Thanks, this was truly an eye opener!!! While this lets the canvas scroll the way I want, it leaves me with the new problem that I have to position the frames manually on the canvas, or did I get this wrong? In my application amount and size of frames will vary - so I was hoping that I can create each frame and leave it to some sort of layout manager to put them nicely on top of each other... Is there a chance that I can achieve this? (I'm not stuck with the canvas widget, I'm just looking for any working combinations of widgets in order to get the desired layout...)

Comment: Yes, you have to position them manually. Typically what I do is create a frame for all the content, and pack (or grid, or place) the content in that frame. Then I just have to add that one frame to the canvas. It becomes very manageable that way. Another trick is to bind to the `<Configure>` event of the canvas -- it will get triggered whenever the canvas is resized. You can then use information from that event to resize that one frame to exactly fit the width of the canvas.

Comment: Thanks again, I will do it the way you proposed.